# codeigniter cant upload image

Tags: image, codeigniter, continuous-integration

i have a problem with codeigniter upload form

View.php I found this code in Codeigniter documentation and i dont know where is the problem..

```
    <?php echo $error;?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

upload.php Thats upload.php

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Upload extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
  }
     ?>
```

When i upload some image ci give me

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Upload::$upload

Filename: controllers/Upload.php

Line Number: 52

Backtrace:
    Fatal error: Call to a member function do_upload() on a non-object in
```

Where is the problem ?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

From the link you posted I followed the guide on uploading the file and it worked perfectly fine.

Make sure you have CI setup properly:

The folders `application` and `system` and the file `index.php` must be uploaded to your working webserver, you must then create a folder called `uploads`, make sure this folder is writable by the proper user, for my system it is `www-data`. I'm using apache2 with linux so my webroot is `var/www`.

So you should see in the primary folder:

- application
- system
- uploads
- index.php

After you do that you will go to:

`localhost/index.php/upload/` or your proper path for `index.php/upload/` and test this again.

Comment: Same problem man ... Im trying 3-4 upload forms and dont works .. always give me this problem ...

Comment: Ok give me a few minutes and I will work over this problem with you.

Comment: Ok thx. I dont know why this form dont work... Everything looks ok

Comment: The only thing I noticed was the missing post field in the do_upload() function, looking over everything again.

Comment: I replaced 
$error['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

and

$data = $this->upload->data(); // It's already an array of data

and again i have same problem.. i dont know reinstall ci and dont work. May be i should to load some library i dont know.

I tried everything and always give me thats problem...

Comment: `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` loads the upload library, I will post a working sample for you to test.

Comment: @user3576620 please view the updated answer, I tested the solution and it worked fine.

Comment: Again give me error in this line
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image')){  
and Message: Undefined property: Upload::$upload
Fatal error: Call to a member function do_upload() on a non-object i

Comment: change your function named `function do_upload()` to `addfile()` and change your form call to `action="<?=site_url('upload/addfile');?>"` The problem is your calling a built in function and your function name matches it.

Comment: I tried this and doesn't work ...

Message: Call to a member function addfile() on a non-object

Message: Undefined property: Upload::$upload

Comment: Try making your functions public please, `public function __construct` `public function do_upload()` etc..

Comment: All functions are public ... I tried everything and i dont know where is the problem ..

Comment: The code I posted works fine on my system, you have an issue with your overall setup.

Comment: in my system doesn't work.. I am useing ci ver3.0 but in documentation everything with upload forms is same...

Comment: The latest is Version 2.1.4

Comment: http://ci3docs.dannynunez.com/ CodeIgniter v3.0.0 (Current version)
CodeIgniter v2.1.4

Comment: @user3576620 3.0 hasn't been released yet, when you click the download link it shows 2.1.4

Comment: @user3576620 I downloaded CI from the link you provided, followed the instructions and I had no errors, please see my edit.